# super ключевое слово и разбор

Tags: java

Из всего кода совсем не понимаю как отрабатывает ключевое слово super.
Во всех моментах этого кода, помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

```
 public abstract class AbstractPhone {
    int year;

    public AbstractPhone(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }

    public abstract void call(int outputNumber);

    public abstract void ring(int inputNumber);

}

public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
            }

    public void callAnotherUser(int number, AbstractPhone phone){
// вот он полиморфизм - использование в коде абстактного типа AbstractPhone phone!
        phone.call(number);
    }
  }
 }



public class ThomasEdisonPhone extends AbstractPhone {

public ThomasEdisonPhone(int year) {
    super(year);
}
    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вращайте ручку");
        System.out.println("Сообщите номер абонента, сэр");
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}




public class Phone extends AbstractPhone {

    public Phone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вызываю номер" + outputNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}



public class VideoPhone extends AbstractPhone {

    public VideoPhone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }
    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Подключаю видеоканал для абонента " + outputNumber );
    }
    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("У вас входящий видеовызов..." + inputNumber);
    }
  }


AbstractPhone firstPhone = new ThomasEdisonPhone(1879);
AbstractPhone phone = new Phone(1984);
AbstractPhone videoPhone=new VideoPhone(2018);
User user = new User("Андрей");
user.callAnotherUser(224466,firstPhone);
// Вращайте ручку
//Сообщите номер абонента, сэр
user.callAnotherUser(224466,phone);
//Вызываю номер 224466
user.callAnotherUser(224466,videoPhone);
//Подключаю видеоканал для абонента 224466
```

Comment: Где код AbstractPhone ? Конструкторы классов VideoPhone,Phone, ThomasEdissonPhone наследуют AbstractPhone, и при вызове их конструктора например: new Phone(1984); год передается в конструктор класса Phone, а через него , через super, в AbstractPhone

Comment: @Mike Mclaren super используется для вызова конструктора непосредственного родительского класса.

Comment: @GinTasan да в примере тоже его нет + я еще код сам понять могу чтобы дописать код правильно(

Comment: По идее там просто абстрактный класс написать надо(в котором переменная year) , который реализует интерфейс с методами ring и call

Comment: @GinTasan Посмотрите, я добавил абстрактный класс, правильный теперь пример?

Comment: @MikeMclaren нет, неправильно. И компилятор Вам уже об этом сказал. У класса `AbstractPhone` нет конструктора с параметром `int`.

Comment: AbstractPhone(int year){this.year = year;}

Comment: @GinTasan теперь правильно?

Comment: Да, верно, все должно работать, но не в данном виде, ибо код внизу бесхозный, его из main вызывать

Comment: Вообще, я уже все написал на машинке, могу вам скинуть, что бы не мулались, а так же советую почитать базовую литературу

Comment: @GinTasan напишите в ответ пожалуйста!

Comment: @GinTasan да я вот на платной платформе взял курс и вот такой полиморфизм пример попался :(

Comment: Неожидал, что на платной, такое.. Могу посоветовать просто читать стандартную всеми рекомендуемую литературу, там все имеется, и зачтите ответ, если он вам помог )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только почитайте базовую литературу, а то туго придётся потом

```js
class test{
public static void main(String[] args){

AbstractPhone firstPhone = new ThomasEdisonPhone(1879);
AbstractPhone phone = new Phone(1984);
AbstractPhone videoPhone=new VideoPhone(2018);
User user = new User("Андрей");
user.callAnotherUser(224466,firstPhone);
// Вращайте ручку
//Сообщите номер абонента, сэр
user.callAnotherUser(224466,phone);
//Вызываю номер 224466
user.callAnotherUser(224466,videoPhone);

}
}



 class VideoPhone extends AbstractPhone {

    public VideoPhone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }
    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Подключаю видеоканал для абонента " + outputNumber );
    }
    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("У вас входящий видеовызов..." + inputNumber);
    }
  }
  
  
  
 class Phone extends AbstractPhone {

    public Phone(int year) {
        super(year);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вызываю номер" + outputNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}


 class ThomasEdisonPhone extends AbstractPhone {

public ThomasEdisonPhone(int year) {
    super(year);
}
    @Override
    public void call(int outputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Вращайте ручку");
        System.out.println("Сообщите номер абонента, сэр");
    }

    @Override
    public void ring(int inputNumber) {
        System.out.println("Телефон звонит");
    }
}



 class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
            }

    public void callAnotherUser(int number, AbstractPhone phone){
// вот он полиморфизм - использование в коде абстактного типа AbstractPhone phone!
        phone.call(number);
    }
  };
 


abstract class AbstractPhone {
    int year;

    protected AbstractPhone(int year){this.year = year;}; 
    public abstract void call(int outputNumber);

    public abstract void ring(int inputNumber);

}
```

Comment: Почему-то вот здесь всё красным цветом вышло, User user = new User("Андрей");
user.callAnotherUser(224466,firstPhone);
// Вращайте ручку
//Сообщите номер абонента, сэр
user.callAnotherUser(224466,phone);
//Вызываю номер 224466
user.callAnotherUser(224466,videoPhone);

Comment: Все классы добавили ? Попробуйте перекомпилировать(пересобрать) проект, некоторые среды обработки так могут реагировать, если есть ошибки прикомпиляции, проверьте, добавили ли все классы,все ли правильно, если что , создайте другой проект

Comment: Еще вопрос почему у нас в АбстрактФон  конструктор protected помечен? Я различаю модификаторы доступа, но не понимаю почему он здесь, а не паблик допустим

Comment: У абстрактного класса не может быть экземпляров, а основном такой конструктор используется при наследовании, поэтому, на случай безопасности(инкапсуляция),( и что бы глаза не мозолил:) ) , объявил его protected

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Удачи в разработке , обращайтесь )